# DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE not importing my model classes

Tags: python, django

I read from various posts that you can use DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = APPNAME.settings to import model classes to run with python scripts on the linux command line.  I tried running:

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=dishtank.settings PYTHONPATH=$HOME/pythonDirLocation python pythonScript.py

In my python script I need to import some classes from my model.py file in one of my apps so that I can edit tables inside my database.  Is there anything I am missing for importing all my django settings for running with my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = APPNAME.settings` should be `PROJECT.settings`. I usually avoid that approach, and prefer using `setup_environ` at the top of my standalone script.

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from yourproject import settings

setup_environ(settings)

from yourproject.app.models import YourModel
```

Answer (score 8):

The `setup_environ` solution is [deprecated since version 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#django-core-management-setup-environ), thus a new solution is to follow the guidelines of the [official doc](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django/en/latest/topics/settings.html).

In essence, you need to adapt the code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Deprecated way:
# from django.core.management import setup_environ
# import settings
# setup_environ(settings)

import sys
import os

# If you find a solution that does not need the two paths, please comment!
sys.path.append('$path_to_root_of_project$')
sys.path.append('$path_to_root_of_project$/$project_name$')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = '$project_name$.settings'
from django.conf import settings

# Beginning of your script...
```

Note that a better solution could be (if applicable) to integrate the script in a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/), e.g., `./manage.py my_command`